# Excel: next bigger value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't reach my goal. My target is to find the next higher value in a column. so I got a column of numbers which are not in order. here is an example

```
7897
1000
1341
1245
8967
4234
```

in the column next to it, i want to get the value next higher

```
7897 => 8967
1000 => 1245
1341 => 4234
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have data in A2:A100 try this formula in B2

`=MIN(IF(A$2:A$100>A2,A$2:A$100))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column - if there is no greater value you get zero

**Edit:**

Alternatively you could use this "non-array" version

`=LARGE(A$2:A$100,COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,">"&A2))`

which will give a #NUM! error if there are no greater values - you can replace that error with a blank in Excel 2007 or later by adding an `IFERROR` check like this

`=IFERROR(LARGE(A$2:A$100,COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,">"&A2)),"")`

Comment: +1 for non array. Say no to the performance eating array formula!   ;)